# ModelAdmin filter resets itself

Tags: silverstripe

Is there a way to make ModelAdmin filters more persistent? Currently if you filter, edit a DataObject and come back, the filter is gone. Also prev/next from unclecheese/betterbuttons do not respect the filter. It jumps to the next Object but not necessarily one of the filtered Objects. I think there was a module for 2.4 called RemodelAdmin that did some of this, but since now all is GridFiled based, this seams like something completely different. Has anybody done some work in this direction for SilverStripe >3 or some hint how to achieve this?

Comment: this has been bugging me for a long time too, see this 3 years old ticket where the issue was first documented: http://open.silverstripe.org/ticket/7642. there seems to be part of a solution in a pull request here: https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/pull/3542

Comment: That's an old issue, I was speking about it with Unclecheese 1 year ago: https://github.com/unclecheese/silverstripe-gridfield-betterbuttons/issues/45

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should remove the module better buttons to get the filter to still be present upon selection of "back" or browser back action.

Comment: whoot - can it be that simple? Whit what version of SilverStripe is this behavior given? Honestly GF without better-button feels like a different pain rather than a solution :) I just saw two modules which both could solve the issue https://github.com/Little-Giant/silverstripe-persistentgridfield https://github.com/Tom-Alexander/silverstripe-griddle